# Will deadlocks occur when deleting rows from a table when being added to by another process?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to archive data from a table into another table whilst the original table is in use.  The archival process is to copy the rows into another table and then delete the rows from the original table.  The rows to be archived are selected by a column that has the Identity property.

A factor is that the table from which the rows are being archived will be in use - new rows will be written into the table as the archival process is running.  This is a 24/7 application that cannot be stopped.

The rows that are being deleted are at the low end of the Identity column numbering whilst the new rows will be being added at the end of the table.

My concern is deadlocks.  Is there a chance that deadlocks could occur between the 2 processes?

The archival process will be run from a Stored Procedure?  Should I set the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY to LOW to ensure that if a deadlock does occur that the archival process will be killed and not the running application?

Should I also set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL?

Thanks

Comment: Question asked and answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226500/will-deadlocks-occur-when-deleting-rows-from-a-table-that-is-being-added-to-by-a

Comment: Question answered here: [enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/226500/will-deadlocks-occur-when-deleting-rows-from-a-table-that-is-being-added-to-by-a)

Comment: I have tried both process at once. It wont affect and causes deadlock for deletion process. But it may affect in case of select statement running.